# Strange characters when converting a hex string

Tags: php

I am extracting a hex string from a `.bin` file which contains monitor information from an EDID file. I then am trying to convert the string to human readable value but it's not working. Extracting the string from the bin file works. The string is

`$hex_string = "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";`

I then do the following and get strange characters coming back

```
$a = hex2bin($hex);
var_dump($a);
```

The return is supposed to be a list of all supported resolutions and colro space by that monitor.

Comment: What makes you think the result should be a string?

Comment: I'm assuming it would be a string of all the supported modes

Comment: Your string appears to contain `������VRLB�4x
��WG�'LL!�@:�q8-@X,F@�c�0�pZ��X���!�BlueRiver
   �U�<
      |@sX !"�]^_bcda#
�m8< @hg�]�x����R� �(U@@�c:��r8-@,E�@�c:�q8-@X,E@�c�`, which is the expected result given your HEX string above.

Comment: Thanks. Yes that is what I am seeing. IS there any way to change that to human? Output should be something like this:                        Pixel Clock: 0MHz 
Horizontal Active: 0 
Horizontal Blanking: 0 
Vertical Active: 0 
Vertical Blanking: 0 
Horizontal Sync Offset: 0 
Horizontal Sync Pulse: 0 
Vertical Sync Offset: 0 
Vertical Sync Pulse: 0 
Horizontal Display Size: 0 
Vertical Display Size: 0 
Horizontal Border: 
Vertical Border: 
Interlaced: false 
Stereo Mode: 0 
Sync Type: 0

Comment: You can't do something like that with binary data. It doesn't represent human-readable string.

Comment: If I knew what type of encoding is used for these EDID files, i can then use PHP to decode it?